# Minimal covering circle

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

There are n points on the plane, how can one approximately find the minimal radius of a circle that covers some k out of n these points? Number n is supposed to be less then 10^4.

There is [lots of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) on the case k==n in Wikipedia, but I found nothing on general case.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, would fit better on https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You're going to have to brute force your way through this one. If, say, n==100 and k==3, you're just going to have to go through each combination of 3 points to find the one that has the smallest circle. You can quickly eliminate some combinations by checking if the distance between any two of the points is greater than the smallest diameter found so far.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about algorithm design, not about implementation. It has been [reposted on Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/31960/minimal-covering-circle) where it is squarely on-topic.

Comment: We've had this discussion on Meta many times. Questions like this are *de facto* on topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an algorithm that, given a radius `r > 0` and an approximation constant `c > 0`, either returns a circle of radius `(1+c) r` enclosing at least `k` points or declares that there is no circle of radius `r` strictly enclosing at least `k` points. The running time is `O(n (1 + k^-1 c^-2 log c^-1))`, which, when used in conjunction with binary search to obtain a sufficiently coarse estimate, should be faster than tmyklebu's algorithm. (To initialize the search, it's possible in time `O(n^2)` to get a `2`-approximation for `r` by looping over the points and running quickselect to find the `k`th closest other point.)

Partition the points by placing point `(x, y)` in a square bin labeled `(floor(x/(2r)), floor(y/(2r)))`. Every circle of radius `r` has an interior that overlaps at most four bins. If there exists a circle of radius `r` enclosing at least `k` points, then there exist `i, j` such that the bins `(i, j), (i, j+1), (i+1, j), (i+1, j+1)` together hold at least `k` points.

For each of these subproblems, place each involved point `(x, y)` in a smaller square bin, `(floor(x/w), floor(y/w))`, where `w = cr/(3sqrt(1/2))` is a sufficiently small width. Now prepare an `O(c^-1)` by `O(c^-1)` matrix where each entry tells how many points are contained in the corresponding bin. Convolve this matrix in two dimensions with a zero-one matrix indicating the bins completely contained in a radius-`(1+c)r` circle. The latter matrix might look like

```
01110
11111
11111
11111
01110.
```

Now we know for each center on the grid a number that is lowerbounded by how many points a circle of radius `r` would contain and upperbounded by how many points a circle of radius `(1+c) r` would contain.

Comment: If your points have integer or floating-point coordinates, the 2-approximation step is unnecessary since binary search works properly on integers and on floating-point numbers.  If they don't and you're working with real numbers, you still only need to blow up n/k circles to get a 3- or 4-approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Given a candidate radius `r`, you can find the maximum number of points that can be contained by a circle of radius `r` by taking every pair `(p1, p2)` of points and seeing how many points are contained by each of the two circles of radius r with `p1` and `p2` on the boundary.

Knowing this, you can binary search for the smallest `r` such that some circle of radius `r` contains `k` or more points.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately the time complexity is O(n^3) with n=10^4.

Comment: It's not.  Fix `p1`.  There are `n-1` points other than `p1`.  Bolt a radius-r circle to `p1` and spin it around; each point other than `p1` will enter and leave the circle at most once per revolution.

Comment: Well, then `O(iterations * n^2 log n)` with `O(n log n)` from sort - but it seems to be too slow anyway.

Comment: @tmyklebu If you were revolving a half-line bolted at p1 and sweeping through the points keep track of when points cross the angle sweep,I agree this is faster than O(n^2) per point p1. But you are revolving a circle of radius r, and figuring out when points enter and leave is non-trivial. I suggest more detail on how you will beat O(n^3), keeping in mind that the number of binary search steps is tied to numeric precision which could be arbitrary.

Comment: user2566092: Fix r and p1. One can precalculate angles at which point enters and leave circle and sort them, then it will take linear time - as with revolving line.

Comment: @user2566092: It's arithmetic.

Comment: How to choose value of "r"?

Answer (score -2):

One thought is that you could take the average of all of the points as the center, then grow the radius until you've covered k points.  Under fairly uniform distributions this would probably do a pretty good job, but would fail for "clumpy" data.  For example, if the points were in two tight clusters far from each other and k was small enough to just necessitate one of them, this would fail spectacularly.  If there's the possibility for this clumping, consider using a clustering algorithm to identify local clusters, and then if one of them contains enough points use the algorithm just on that cluster.

Comment: This will not work. The center changes as you consider different sets of k points. See my comment to the OP above.

Comment: OP also said "approximately", which I take to mean finding an okay answer but not necessarily the optimal one.

Comment: @se0808, what do you mean by "approximately" in your original post? How approximate? Within 10% of the minimum? 50%?

Comment: @Johathan M, with a given precision - I meant something like binary search.